# Is there a semantic way of using 3 select boxes to choose 'Date of Birth'?

Tags: forms, xhtml, label, w3c, semantic-markup

I'm currently building a web form and I need users to enter their DOB.

I have used 3 select boxes at the moment. One for the Day, one for the Month and one for the Year.

I have wrapped them within a 'Date of Birth' label and styled things up with CSS.

Everything looks ok, but when I go to validate things, I get the following error:

***" The label element may contain at most one input, button, select, textarea, or keygen descendant "***

It would be good to hear if there is a better way of doing this or any semantic alternatives?

Thanks in advance :o)

ps - I had to include a br within the label too, this is to get the select boxes to clear the label text. I've wrapped the select boxes within my label tag for positioning purposes, as my form is made up of a two column layout. There doesn't seem to be a validation issue with the br where it is. So hoping it's ok...

Here's what things look like atm:

[image: Date of Birth select boxes]

and here's my code atm:

```
<label id="date_of_birth">Date of Birth:<br />
                    <select class="first" name="date_of_birth:day" tabindex="7">
                        <option value="">
                        <!-- -->
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="22">22</option>
                        <option value="23">23</option>
                        <option value="24">24</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="26">26</option>
                        <option value="27">27</option>
                        <option value="28">28</option>
                        <option value="29">29</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="31">31</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="date_of_birth:mon" tabindex="8">
                        <option value="">
                        <!-- -->
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">Jan</option>
                        <option value="2">Feb</option>
                        <option value="3">Mar</option>
                        <option value="4">Apr</option>
                        <option value="5">May</option>
                        <option value="6">Jun</option>
                        <option value="7">Jul</option>
                        <option value="8">Aug</option>
                        <option value="9">Sep</option>
                        <option value="10">Oct</option>
                        <option value="11">Nov</option>
                        <option value="12">Dec</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="date_of_birth:year" tabindex="9">
                        <option value="">
                        <!-- -->
                        </option>
                        <option value="1920">1920</option>
                        <option value="1921">1921</option>
                        <option value="1922">1922</option>
                        <option value="1923">1923</option>
                        <option value="1924">1924</option>
                        <option value="1925">1925</option>
                        <option value="1926">1926</option>
                        <option value="1927">1927</option>
                        <option value="1928">1928</option>
                        <option value="1929">1929</option>
                        <option value="1930">1930</option>
                        <option value="1931">1931</option>
                        <option value="1932">1932</option>
                        <option value="1933">1933</option>
                        <option value="1934">1934</option>
                        <option value="1935">1935</option>
                        <option value="1936">1936</option>
                        <option value="1937">1937</option>
                        <option value="1938">1938</option>
                        <option value="1939">1939</option>
                        <option value="1940">1940</option>
                        <option value="1941">1941</option>
                        <option value="1942">1942</option>
                        <option value="1943">1943</option>
                        <option value="1944">1944</option>
                        <option value="1945">1945</option>
                        <option value="1946">1946</option>
                        <option value="1947">1947</option>
                        <option value="1948">1948</option>
                        <option value="1949">1949</option>
                        <option value="1950">1950</option>
                        <option value="1951">1951</option>
                        <option value="1952">1952</option>
                        <option value="1953">1953</option>
                        <option value="1954">1954</option>
                        <option value="1955">1955</option>
                        <option value="1956">1956</option>
                        <option value="1957">1957</option>
                        <option value="1958">1958</option>
                        <option value="1959">1959</option>
                        <option value="1960">1960</option>
                        <option value="1961">1961</option>
                        <option value="1962">1962</option>
                        <option value="1963">1963</option>
                        <option value="1964">1964</option>
                        <option value="1965">1965</option>
                        <option value="1966">1966</option>
                        <option value="1967">1967</option>
                        <option value="1968">1968</option>
                        <option value="1969">1969</option>
                        <option value="1970">1970</option>
                        <option value="1971">1971</option>
                        <option value="1972">1972</option>
                        <option value="1973">1973</option>
                        <option value="1974">1974</option>
                        <option value="1975">1975</option>
                        <option value="1976">1976</option>
                        <option value="1977">1977</option>
                        <option value="1978">1978</option>
                        <option value="1979">1979</option>
                        <option value="1980">1980</option>
                        <option value="1981">1981</option>
                        <option value="1982">1982</option>
                        <option value="1983">1983</option>
                        <option value="1984">1984</option>
                        <option value="1985">1985</option>
                        <option value="1986">1986</option>
                        <option value="1987">1987</option>
                        <option value="1988">1988</option>
                        <option value="1989">1989</option>
                        <option value="1990">1990</option>
                        <option value="1991">1991</option>
                        <option value="1992">1992</option>
                        <option value="1993">1993</option>
                        <option value="1994">1994</option>
                        <option value="1995">1995</option>
                        <option value="1996">1996</option>
                        <option value="1997">1997</option>
                        <option value="1998">1998</option>
                        <option value="1999">1999</option>
                        <option value="2000">2000</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a suggestion [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?554911-One-label-multiple-controls) that structures a DOB appropriately for assistive technology that might help answer your question (in your case the `<input>`'s would be replaced with `<select>`'s:

> This is how I'd tend to do it (I'm not saying it's necessarily the
>   best way, mind you): I have visible text for sighted users, and have
>   css-positioned text offscreen for screen reader users where it will be
>   picked up and correctly associated with the appropriate controls.

```
Birthdate:            
<fieldset id="birthdate">
  <label for="birthday_day" class="offset">Birthday Day</label>
  <input type="text" name="birthday_day" id="birthday_day" size="2" maxlength="2" value="" />

  <label for="birthday_month" class="offset">Birthday Month</label>
  <input type="text" name="birthday_month" id="birthday_month" size="2" maxlength="2" value="" />

  <label for="birthday_year" class="offset">Birthday Year</label>
  <input type="text" name="birthday_year" id="birthday_year" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" />
</fieldset>
```

> ...you need a label for each control, otherwise assistive technology
>   will struggle with it - it will just say "edit:" and someone won't
>   necessarily know what they are supposed to put in each field. This
>   method tells the assistive technology without taking up screen real
>   estate.

Comment: I like this idea! So you'd hide the label text offscreen and only show the inputs? What tag would you use for the Birthdate: text?

Comment: If you want to display the overall title in the header for the `fieldset`, the appropriate tag would be `<legend>`, and it would go inside of the `<fieldset>` tag at the top.

Answer (score 1):

my code , very simple,using jquery: [codepen](https://codepen.io/abdulmalik101/pen/dJOJov)

HTML :

```
<form class = "container">
    <label >birthday<span>*</span></label>
    <SELECT id ="year" name = "yyyy" onchange="change_year(this)">
    </SELECT>
    <SELECT  id ="month" name = "mm" onchange="change_month(this)">
    </SELECT>
    <SELECT id ="day" name = "dd" >
    </SELECT>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var Days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];// index => month [0-11]
$(document).ready(function(){
    var option = '<option value="day">day</option>';
    var selectedDay="day";
    for (var i=1;i <= Days[0];i++){ //add option days
        option += '<option value="'+ i + '">' + i + '</option>';
    }
    $('#day').append(option);
    $('#day').val(selectedDay);

    var option = '<option value="month">month</option>';
    var selectedMon ="month";
    for (var i=1;i <= 12;i++){
        option += '<option value="'+ i + '">' + i + '</option>';
    }
    $('#month').append(option);
    $('#month').val(selectedMon);

    var d = new Date();
    var option = '<option value="year">year</option>';
    selectedYear ="year";
    for (var i=1930;i <= d.getFullYear();i++){// years start i
        option += '<option value="'+ i + '">' + i + '</option>';
    }
    $('#year').append(option);
    $('#year').val(selectedYear);
});
function isLeapYear(year) {
    year = parseInt(year);
    if (year % 4 != 0) {
          return false;
      } else if (year % 400 == 0) {
          return true;
      } else if (year % 100 == 0) {
          return false;
      } else {
          return true;
      }
}

function change_year(select)
{
    if( isLeapYear( $(select).val() ) )
      {
            Days[1] = 29;
            if( $("#month").val() == 2)
            {
                   var day = $('#day');
                   var val = $(day).val();
                   $(day).empty();
                   var option = '<option value="day">day</option>';
                   for (var i=1;i <= Days[1];i++){ //add option days
                         option += '<option value="'+ i + '">' + i + '</option>';
             }
                   $(day).append(option);
                   if( val > Days[ month ] )
                   {
                          val = 1;
                   }
                   $(day).val(val);
             }
    }
    else {
        Days[1] = 28;
    }
}

function change_month(select) {
    var day = $('#day');
    var val = $(day).val();
    $(day).empty();
    var option = '<option value="day">day</option>';
    var month = parseInt( $(select).val() ) - 1;
    for (var i=1;i <= Days[ month ];i++){ //add option days
        option += '<option value="'+ i + '">' + i + '</option>';
    }
    $(day).append(option);
    if( val > Days[ month ] )
    {
        val = 1;
    }
    $(day).val(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code for date of birth , select box.

code:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>


     var setyear=0;
      var setmonth=0;
      var dayarray=new Array("31","28","31","30","31","30","31","31","30","31","30","31");
    function onchangeyear(val){
            setyear=val;
            var dayoption='<option value="">Day</option>';
           // dayarray[val-1];
           if(setmonth!=0){
               if(val%4==0 && setmonth==2) {
                   for(var i=1;i<=parseInt((dayarray[setmonth-1]))+1;i++)  {
                    dayoption +='<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'; 
              }
          }else{
              for(var i=1;i<=parseInt(dayarray[setmonth-1]);i++)  {
                dayoption +='<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'; 
          }      
        }
       $('#day').html(dayoption);
   }else{
         for(var i=1;i<=31;i++)  {
         dayoption +='<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'; 
     }
      $('#day').html(dayoption);
   }
}



 function onchangemonth(val){
               setmonth=val;
               var dayoption='<option value="">Day</option>';
             // dayarray[val-1];
              if(setyear!=0){
           if(setyear%4==0 && val==2) {
                 for(var i=1;i<=parseInt((dayarray[val-1]))+1;i++)  {
                 dayoption +='<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'; 
              }
           }else{
                for(var i=1;i<=(dayarray[val-1]);i++)  {
                dayoption +='<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'; 
           }      
       }
           $('#day').html(dayoption);
   }else{
         for(var i=1;i<=dayarray[val-1];i++)  {
              dayoption +='<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'; 
       }
        $('#day').html(dayoption);
   }
}




    </script>



   <label id="date_of_birth">Date of Birth:<br />
   <select class="first" name="date_of_birth:day" tabindex="7" id="day">
          <option value="">--day--</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
            -------------------------
          <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>     

    <select name="date_of_birth:mon" tabindex="8" id="month" onchange="onchangemonth(this.value)">
          <option value="">month</option>
          <option value="1">Jan</option>
            -------------------   
          <option value="12">Dec</option>
    </select>


     <select name="date_of_birth:year" tabindex="9" id="year" onchange="onchangeyear(this.value)">
          <option value=""> years</option>
          <option value="1920">1920</option>         
               ----------------     
           <option value="2010">2010</option>       
           <option value="2011">2011</option> 
           <option value="2012">2012</option>      

     </select>

 </label>
```